# Renaming Files using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I would like to rename files as per date using a batch file. Now my challenge is, in case the file name exists it should append a (1).. (2).. (3) on every file at the end.

```
ren c:\LogFiles\*.log BackupLog-%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.log
```

I would also like to know if its possible to

- Rename the files as per previous date, that is -1 of the current date (if i execute the batch file today it renames as per yesterday's date.
- Rename files as per date created.

In case its not possible with batch file please assist with power shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for your append question:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "logpath=c:\LogFiles"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /od "%logpath%\*.log"') do call:doit "%logpath%\%%~a"
goto:eof

:doit
setlocal
set "npre=BackupLog-%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%"
:loop
if defined fcnt (set "nname=%npre% (%fcnt%)%~x1") else set "nname=%npre%%~x1"
set /a cnt+=1
set "fcnt=00%cnt%"
set "fcnt=%fcnt:~-3%"
if exist "%logpath%\%nname%" goto:loop
echo ren "%~1" "%nname%"
ren "%~1" "%nname%"
endlocal
exit /b
```

If you have more questions please make [new questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Thanks men will try it