# Rename file using batch file

Tags: batch-file, rename

I know there are many examples of this but I just can't get it and this shouldn't be THAT difficult but I am finding it to be.

I have a folder with 4 files in it:

```
rtcc_current_pnp_data1-2018-12-26-061000.txt
rtcc_current_pnp_data2-2018-12-26-061000.txt
rtcc_current_pnp_data3-2018-12-26-061000.txt
rtcc_current_pnp_data4-2018-12-26-061000.txt
```

the date/time at the end changes daily.

Each day I want to run a batch file to rename these to:

```
data1.txt 
data2.txt
data3.txt 
data4.txt
```

That's it...can someone please help me extract the correct name from the files and rename them?

So I tried this and it doesn't do anything:

```
for %%A in (\\apdwhdb01\D$\ProbationImportFolder\Current\rtcc*.*) do (
  set "filename=%%A"
  set "newName=EXP_!filename:~18!"

  rem ** remove the ECHO when it seems to work
  ren !filename! !newName!
)
```

Comment: As you say, there are many examples, please read them, create your code, then come back here to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53937620/edit), if the code you've written doesn't perform as written and intended. You would then post a [mcve] of the code after, having followed the advice provided in [ask]. _Technically this topic should be closed as a duplicate, so I'd suggest that you consider my advice sooner rather than later._

Comment: I also tried this:
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28127794/Batch-script-to-parse-a-date-out-of-a-filename.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140044/renaming-files-using-batch-file

https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_rename.php

I apologize for not providing more details but I have been searching all day for this and am very frustrated

Comment: It's your responsibility to put together some code from the examples you've found, not ours. Whilst I appreciate that it's not always a simple task to piece together code when it's not familiar to you, it is both courteous to the Membership and the Site itself, to show some effort.

Comment: I have tried to put together code from the examples and have failed - that is why I asked for help.  Part of the reason I am struggling is because I can't find any explanation of what all those commands do. I don't even know what terms to search for to figure out what this is doing 

@echo off
pushd "pathToYourFolder" || exit /b
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *_*.jpg') do (
  for /f "tokens=1* eol=_ delims=_" %%A in ("%%~nF") do ren "%%F" "%%~nB_%%A%%~xF"
)
popd from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013145/windows-batch-file-rename

Comment: To find out what a command does, open a Command Prompt window and enter the command with the question mark option, _e.g. `For /?`, `Set /?`, `Ren /?`..._.

Comment: `I can't find any explanation of what all those commands do`: You should bookmark [SS64])(https://ss64.com/nt/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is with this:

```
 ren "\\apdwhdb01\D$\ProbationImportFolder\Current\*data1*.txt" data1.txt
 ren "\\apdwhdb01\D$\ProbationImportFolder\Current\*data2*.txt" data2.txt
 ren "\\apdwhdb01\D$\ProbationImportFolder\Current\*data3*.txt" data3.txt
 ren "\\apdwhdb01\D$\ProbationImportFolder\Current\*data4*.txt" data4.txt
```

However, the problem you are probably facing is that the network connection isn't active/valid for your connection. The easiest way to find out is with this:

```
 dir "\\apdwhdb01\D$\ProbationImportFolder\Current"
```

If it returns your file list then you're okay. If not then you'll want to map the drive first in the same batch file:

```
 :: temporarily map the network share to the Q: drive.
 :: make sure you update the username and password
 net use q: "\\apdwhdb01\D$\ProbationImportFolder\Current" /user:MyUserName myPassword

 :: rename the files
 ren "q:\*data1*.txt" data1.txt
 ren "q:\*data2*.txt" data2.txt
 ren "q:\*data3*.txt" data3.txt
 ren "q:\*data4*.txt" data4.txt

 :: remove the mapped drive
 net use q: /delete
```

Comment: thank you, I was making it way more complicated than it needed to be!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

pushd "\\apdwhdb01\D$\ProbationImportFolder\Current" || exit /b 1

for %%A in (data1 data2 data3 data4) do (
    for %%B in ("rtcc_current_pnp_%%~A-20*.txt") do (
        ren "%%~B" "%%~A.txt"
    )
)

popd
```

The `pushd` will map the network share to a temporary mapped drive.
The `||` is if the command on the left fails,
do the command on the right,
which is `exit /b 1` that ends the script.

The `for` loop iterates through
`data1`, `data2`, `data3` and `data4`.

The nested `for` loop iterates the file names using `%%A`
with a value of i.e. `data1`, and uses a wildcard for the datestamp variation.
`%~B` is the current filename which is renamed to `%%~A.txt`,
in which `%%~A` holds the current value of i.e `data1`.
The `~` in `%%~A` is a modifier which will remove surrounding double quotes.

The `popd` will retore the previous current working directory
that `pushd` changed. It should remove the temporary mapped drive.

To get help on a command, use i.e. `pushd /?`, which will print
out help information.
`for /?` prints help information about `for`, `ren /?` ... etc.

Comment: Thank you!  I will check this out tomorrow when I get to work. I appreciate your explanation and feel that I will actually learn something.

Answer (score 0):

A two line script example:

```bat
@PushD "\\apdwhdb01\D$\ProbationImportFolder\Current" 2>Nul || Exit /B
@For %%A In ("rtcc_*.txt") Do @For /F "Tokens=4 Delims=_-" %%B In ("%%A") Do @Ren "%%A" "EXP_%%B%%~xA"
```

*For information on the commands used, open a Command Prompt and enter each of:*

> PushD /?
>   Exit /?
>   For /?
>   Ren /?